# Is using a JSON file as a database secure?

Tags: sql, json, database

I am wondering if using a json file on our computer as a database is secure? And if it is more secure to use sql?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "secure".

Comment: A json file is a plain text file, so anyone with access to that filesystem can read it

Comment: Any database may be more performant than reading and writing a json file

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Any data that is not encrypted at rest can be read by anyone who has access to that filesystem. It might be a bit more complicated to get the data out of a MSSQL Data file than from a JSON file, but if one knows what filetype he is dealing with, it's not a big deal either. So in that sense a DBMS is not per se more secure than a JSON file. And you can also encrypt the contents of a JSON file if you want to ...

Comment: And also the statement about the performance may depend on the usecase and how much data is to be managed and what operations are needed. Generally I agree with you, that for a certain amount of data, a DBMS will probably be better. But if there are only a few records, you might not need the overhead of a complete dbms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A json file isn't secure to use as database as you acn access to it easily
You can use Nosql database like [MongoDb](https://www.mongodb.com/) wich stores data as JSON documents